# unity-music-daemon uses large amount of memory

Tags: package-management, startup, ram, memory-usage

When I boot my Ubuntu 13.04 up, I noticed that my fans goes crazy and when I had a glanced at System Monitor, I saw that a process called `unity-music-daemon` is using a large amount of memory and CPU. I found on internet that uninstallation of `unity-lens-music` package will solve this issue. What I want to know is what `unity-music-daemon` does. Since uninstalling it solves this problem, I hope this package has nothing to do with music players or audio. Can anybody explain what this daemon does?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am far from an expert on the topic but given that no one with more knowledge on it has answered I will try to provide a very rough idea to you.

As far as I understand "lens" is the generic term for the search functionality of the Ubuntu Dash (Dash being the thing that appears when you click the upper-left corner in the default installation). So, you can have a Wikipeda lens for example which will allow you to search for Wikipedia related information using the Dash.

On the other hand daemons are processes that run on the background and take care of having your system running smoothly and up to date (as far as my knowledge goes).

With this two things above we can state that `unity-music-daemon` takes care of keeping the data-based updated and running smoothly for music related queries.